# IIS server not loading the database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have created a website using asp.net every thing is running fine when i run this using visual studio development server  but when i tried to run it by IIS server then Home page of website loads but it couldn't make connection with database server

```
<add connectionString="Data Source=ASHUTOSH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CloudStorage;Integrated Security=True" name="connectionStr"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

this works fine on visual studio develoment server but not with IIS.... Please help

Comment: Please include the connection string and please include the username that the app pool that your application is running under.

Comment: @Aron I have upadated please check

Comment: You IIs service account does not have rights to connect to the database.\

Comment: @Hogan what should i do to connect it

Comment: @AshutoshSinghRathore - Change the connection string to use a user that has rights or give the service account rights. (Depends on your setup and version what user -- ASPNET or NETWORKSERVICES or others.)  Check SQL server logs to see who tried to connect.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `Integrated Security=True` you use the application pool identity to connect to the DB. When you run Cassini, you use your own credentials. You should set up the application pool identity with a user that has permissions to login and query SQL Server.

Comment: @AshutoshSinghRathore - And did you give `Network Service` permissions on your DB?

Comment: As i am new to this Domain. Can u please tell how to grant permission to db in sql express..

Comment: You need `Management Studio` This is a good reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx. Make sure to provide all the db roles needed to run your code.

Comment: I would suggest two things: 1. Try running management studio as the app pool user and see if you can login and query the DB. 2. Try and use SQL Server authentication to rule out other issues and make sure the issue is with the Windows authentication.

Comment: Thanks for help i think the problem was with the windows authentication I changed it to sql server and it is working fine now

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> When you run a page using the ASP.NET **Development Server**, **the page runs in the context of your current user account**. For example, if you are running as an administrator-level user, a page running in the ASP.NET Development Server will have administrator-level privileges. In contrast, **in IIS**, ASP.NET **by default runs in the context of the special user (ASPNET or NETWORK SERVICES)** that typically has limited privileges. The ASPNET or NETWORK SERVICES accounts are local to the server computer (not domain accounts), which restricts access to resources on other computers.
>
> **Database access**
> When working with the ASP.NET Development Server, you can typically rely on Windows Integrated authentication to access SQL Server. However, when the same page runs in IIS under the ASPNET or NETWORK SERVICES account, the page is running in the context of a local user, and you often have to **configure the page to use a connection string that includes information about a user and password**. For details, see [Accessing SQL Server from a Web Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht43wsex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [ASP.NET Security Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yedba920%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).